# Grab and drop object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying new things and I'm stuck to find a way to drag and drop objects. My player is a square and he have a hand attached. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

That red thing in the arm is the "hand", when I press shift it turns green. I made the detection like a ground check. Here is the code:

```
void Update () {
        touch = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(touchDetect.position, 0.01f, objectLayer);
        mao1.SetBool("Ligado", ligado);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            ligado = true;
        } else {
            ligado = false;
        }        
    }
```

The touchDetect is working fine, because he turns to "true" when touches the box:

[image: Example2]

My question is: I don't know how to put in the script that I want him to grab the object and drop when I want to. If I need to use Raycast, how would the code looks like?

Comment: What type of object is that? Sprite Image or Cube with texture? If that is cube then just attach your cube with that hand object or child it with hand

Comment: It's a sprite image, it's a 2D game. And I don't know anything about the 3D features haha

Comment: Any Improvement you got from my answer

Comment: I don't know what I need to do inside "Collide conditions" and "DropCondition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "grab" an object in unity, simply set the `transform.parent` of the gameobject you wish to grab, to the transform of the gameobject you wish to grab it with.

For example, in your code you are using `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` which returns a `Collider2D` object.  You can use that collider to grab on to your gameobject.

```
Collider2D touch = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(touchDetect.position, 0.01f, objectLayer);

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && touch != null) 
{
    //grab on to the object
    touch.gameObject.transform.parent = this.transform;

    //if your box has a rigidbody on it,and you want to take direct control of it
    //you will want to set the rigidbody iskinematic to true.
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
} 
else if( touch != null)
{
    //let the object go
    touch.gameObject.transform.parent = null;

    //if your object has a rigidbody be sure to turn kinematic back to false
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
}
```

Comment: This is working , but when I grab the object, it falls out of my hand

Comment: I'm confused.  Could you elaborate what is happening more?

Comment: ![Example](https://i.gyazo.com/3585bd745afe41da2ecd1078a7279bf8.gif) As you can see, I disabled collision between the player and the box layer

Comment: Ah I see. Does your box have a rigidbody2d component attached? If so, you probably need to disable gravity so it does not effect the object you are picking up while you are holding it. – James Hogle 7 mins ago

Comment: Ah, understood. Is there a way that I can disable gravity only when i'm holding the object?

Comment: I have updated my answer, see if that works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I just attached a GameObject to the cube inside the script, and instead gravityScale I enable .isKinematic, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just place a GameObject with SprieRender component attach it to hand tip.

Put this script to that qube and follow what I commented

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class collid : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

public Sprite mySprite; // Put Here that Qube Sprite
public GameObject Cursorimg; // Put the gameobject here from hierarchy

void Start () {
    mySprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Collide conditions) {
     Debug.Log(" Collide ");
     Cursorimg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;
     Cursorimg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 3;// U change based on your option
    }
    if(DropCondition)
    {
     Debug.Log("Drop");
     Cursorimg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite =null;
    }
}
```

If this not works Here is a script that gameobject with Sprite will follow mouse position,

```
    Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
    pos.z = Cursorimg.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
    Cursorimg.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
```

this code follows in update and Cursorimg is Gameobject

I think This would help you, Let me know further